# How to check a check box in Haml using check_box_tag

Tags: html, ruby, checkbox, haml

Can someone tell me how to set these check boxes to checked? I'm sure it's simple, but after an hour of trying i think I need to ask! Thanks!

```
= form_tag movies_path, :id => 'ratings_form', :method => :get do
  Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => 'ratings_submit'
```

Answer (score 16):

Ref [check_box_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002246)

```
check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]",  1, !!(rating.rating)
```

Your `2nd parameter` must be `value` of checkbox

Your `3rd parameter` must be a `boolean condition` which return `true/false` and depends on it checkbox is `checked/unchecked`

Comment: For rails 5 I only see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box

Answer (score 3):

```
check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]",  1, @selected.include?("#{rating}")
```

where `@selected` is an array with the element selected.

Answer (score 2):

Use true for Checked or false for Unchecked at the end of the line

```
check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", true #checked
```

or

```
check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", false #unchecked
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the api dock, check box tag takes the following options:

`check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`

This means the first value is the name, the second value is a 'value' and the third value is whether the box is checked, which is default to false. So, in order to check or uncheck the box you can do the following:

```
- if (some condition)
  = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", "anystring", true
- else 
  = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]"
```

The second line just puts a random string into the value field because in this case it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by Sali. Strangely, the `check_box_tag` returns a checkbox with no label text. Here's how you can display text if you're iterating over an array.

```
- Puppies.each do |puppy|
  = check_box_tag(puppy.name, puppy.name, puppy.goodboy?)
  = puppy.name
```

Answer (score -3):

```
= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]",{},{:checked => ""}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add some explanation? And btw if you take [SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), you will get your first shiny badge ;)