# Rails: How to read out a checkbox in a helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I am trying to use a check_box to assign relations between two models, projects and userroles. In my view it looks like the following:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#EEFAFF"><%= link_to project.name, project %></td>
    <% if project.beginn? %>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#EEFFFF"><%= project.beginn.to_s :date %></td>
    <% else %>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#EEFFFF"><%= '- - - - -' %></td>
    <% end %>
    <% if project.ende? %>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#EEFAFF"><%= project.ende.to_s :date %></td>
    <% else %>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#EEFFFF"><%= '- - - - -' %></td>
    <% end %>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#EEFFFF"><%= project.institut  %></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#EEFFFF"><%= check_box_tag "project", userallowed?(project), project.userroles.size>0 -%></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

While I have no idea what the project variable might be good for, userallowed? is calling a helper method and with project.userroles.size I check wether the two models are related or not. My helper method looks like the following:

```
def userallowed?(projects)
  if @projects        
    @project.userroles << @userrole
  else
    @project.userroles.delete(@userrole)
  end
end
```

The problem here is the if-statement. What variable can I use to find out if the check_box is checked or not. Although I read a lot about checkboxes I think I misunderstand the concept completly.

Comment: How do you post the value of check box??

Comment: I guess this is is form in which you are about to set allow user to project or not. And looks like you are trying to find out it before. This field is value, which you will be parse from response on server (i hope), and it should take `1` or something like that, if it's checked. In third parameter you could choose is it checked or not at start (not sure). http://stackoverflow.com/a/12957409/724036

Comment: are you changing the underlying data while rendering the view? that is a very bad idea. only controllers should change that after you posted the form to an update action or whatever!

Comment: @monga  I don't even know how to access the value of the check box...

Comment: @Alder Yes I want to assign the userroles to projects...which one is the value field? Yes thats exactly what the third parameter is doing...this at least works for me...

Comment: @phoet I change the underlying data in the helper method...is this also a bad idea?

Comment: looks like you don't have a basic understanding of MVC. if you want to learn more about rails it would be good to watch all episodes of railscasts.

Comment: @Tommyknocker second value - '1', means it should be `1` when button checked and `nothing` otherwise. It's be enable after you *submit the form*, *send request* and *get response with this data on the server*. Then you can save as you need. Perhaps you want to show your projects, thats not what checkbox do. You need select box.

Comment: @Alder yes thats good to know...actually what I want to do is not to show my projects but to assign permissions to edit projects for users...thats what userrole is thought to be good for...the userroles and projects are connected via a HABTM connection..right now I am not using a form for this but hoped to add or delete a connection whenever the checkbox is clicked...

Comment: @Tommyknocker ok, then you should add form and submit it remotely by changing checkbox state event, or send ajax request on this event with all necessary data. It's complicated to explain all of this.

Comment: My approach doesn't seem to be very promising, I will try it completly different, thank you!